# wp7 background task out of app

Tags: multithreading, windows-phone-7, background, live-tile

I need to have a background process that runs independent of my app and performs a set of tasks. These tasks need to execute even when my app isn't running. For example, continuously process a list of tasks that contain the date/time they need to be executed on. The background task would iterate over the list and process all of the ones that match the current time.

Is this possible to do locally without the need for a web server and utilizing the push notification services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202942%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) is a link to an overview of Background Agents on Windows Phone. At this point what you want is not possible with any degree of accuracy (periodic background tasks are run only once every half hour at the minimum) or dependability (background agents are disabled if the user does not open the associated app for a while).

So yes, at this time your only option is to create a [push notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402537%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) server and have that notification deep link to whatever app you want to open.

Comment: And may be a delay in the communication between server and client, by many reasons; and my app will be stuck by the web. I'd like to use this at web and locally too. I'm thinking about using a sms server as alternative to web, but is too complicated and I'm very sad :( But thank you, very nice answer!

Comment: Glad to help. Please accept the answer - so the people who stop by later with the same question will know it as such.